# image [background image via CSS] not rendered in IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

I need some help as to the reason IE7 will not render my image in the following HTML/CSS code

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta name="generator" content="HTML Tidy for Linux (vers 25 March 2009), see www.w3.org" />
      <title>Debugging IE 7 image problem</title>
      <style>
         .delete-icon
         {
         background-image: url("http://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/momenticons-basic/16x16/trash-can-delete.png");
         background-position: top right;
         background-repeat: no-repeat;
         padding-right: 18px;
         margin-left: 7px;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <table id="table_Locations">
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
               <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="div-input-default" id="LocationsTest2">
               <td>
                  <select name="AllTests_Locations_Substance_2" id="LocationsTest2">
                     <option value="641">Okuku</option>
                     <option value="644">Oyan</option>
                     <option value="645">Ikirun</option>
                     <option value="646">Oshogbo</option>
                  </select>
               </td>
               <td>
                    <input id="LocationsTestResults2_negative" name="AllTests_Locations_Result_2" value="776" type="radio" />Negative <input id="LocationsTestResults2_positive" name="AllTests_Locations_Result_2" value="777" type="radio" />Positive<br />
                    </td>
               <td>
                    <a class="delete-icon" href="#"></a>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

This renders well in IE8, IE9, Firefox and Chrome but not IE7. How can I change this markup to get it  to work in IE7 please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
.delete-icon {
         background: url("http://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/momenticons-basic/16x16/trash-can-delete.png") no-repeat right 0;
         display: inline-block;
         width: 100px; /* set to whatever you need */
         height: 100px; /* set to whatever you need */
         padding-right: 18px;
         margin-left: 7px;
}
```

The key is giving the anchor tag the correct display value plus a width and height.

I'd also recommend that you don't use tables for layout purposes as that hasn't been good practice for at least 10 years or more.

Comment: Thanks, I am well aware of the issues related to the use of tables for layout purposes and do steer clear where possible. Most importantly though, your solution works for me - the combination of the display and the width/height did the trick - not just the width/height as Kappa suggested [thanks to him though]. Thanks again

Comment: @pi. -  No probs, glad to be of help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set width and height to .delete-icon style

Comment: Thanks but that does not work, didn't think it would. Just tried it to confirm. Thanks though